# How to make SVG in Inkscape really scalable?

Tags: resolution, png, svg, inkscape

I wanted to know how to make SVG from a raster picture in Inkscape. I am in Wikipedia which uses lot of SVG's so I want to make a few. I know how to track those PNG and export the bitmap results as high resolution, take for example 2000x2000 pixels. But the problem is my SVF's get pixelated at low-resolutions that is concentrated, otherwise they are good. Plus how to set nominal resolution?

- I use Inkscape to trace
- I export the bitmaps at high-res (2000px)
- Save them as Inkscape SVGs.

Comment: What do you mean by “low-resolutions that is concentrated”? Also, why export anything to bitmaps again – that should be done on the fly by Wikipedia, because bitmaps aren’t scalable? Moreover, if I understand you correctly: Why do you save the file twice (once via “Export Bitmap” and once via normal saving)?

Comment: By low-resolutions that are conc. I mean for eg, take an SVG which is nominally 500x500 pixels, when its rendered as a 200 pixel one, in an article it appears the same way a jpeg or png would when in essence it should not lose quality and should appear in the same way in all sizes since its a Scalable Vector Graphic! While saving as Export Bitmap it gets saved as a PNG not as SVG but for SVG's I need high-res original traces.

Comment: I think you got something wrong about the file formats or how Wikipedia deals with SVGs. If you implement an SVG in a Wikipedia article, you do not get to see the actual SVG, but a bitmap generated from it server-side (I do not know why, but most probably it is to provide compatibility to some stone-age browsers). Take for example any picture in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg): You only get an SVG, if you follow the link behind the image twice. Also note that PNGs are inherently non-scalable, generating them from an SVG cannot change that.

Comment: Yes I know, they are rendered as PNGs. But in lower resolutions, they are perfectly scalable.

Comment: Take a look at SVG's made by me, you'll get an idea, [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mohan_Bagan_FC_Logo.svg), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CIFF_11_Logo_Vector.svg), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:T-series-logo.svg), [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Yash_Raj_Logo.svg).

Comment: For eg. compare two articles, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11th_Chennai_International_Film_Festival). In the first artilce the logo in the infobox, the **SVG** is size is reduced without any apparent loss of quality but on the other hand my one looks a bit hazy. I want the solution to that.

Comment: I can now guess that your problem are vectorisation artifacts, i.e., shapes not being perfectly guessed by the tracer. Could I be right about that?

Comment: Yes you might be.

Comment: I use trace bitmap, which is an automated process.

Comment: Taking a closer look at one of your example images (No. 3), I noticed that it is an SVG which contains nothing but an embedded PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I guessed that your problem are artefacts of an automatic vectorisation. These can be reduced by playing with the parameters of the tracer, but it is unlikely that this suffices to make the final images better than an automatically scaled bitmap.

To make use of the advantages of the SVG (or any other vector format), you have to correct the result of the tracer by hand. E.g., in your [third example picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:T-series-logo.svg), you could make the following improvements (I recommend to start with this, since it is by far the most simple image):

- Use actual rectangles for the rectangles by using Inkscape’s rectangle objects or using a Path object that only consists of four appropriately placed vertices connected with straight lines.
- Use an actual circle objects for the circles.
- Ensure that every line that should be straight actually is, e.g., all the lines that are not at the end of a stroke in the big T.
- Use the original logo font or at least some very similar font for the word *series.* (And yes, the font may be very difficult or impossible to find.)

Of course it might also help to have a high-resolution bitmap to trace from.

Comment: I'll trace it manually, I mean the parts which are not simple shapes like rectangles, or circles for that matter. I'll get back to it then

Comment: Hey Wrzlprmft take a look at my recent uploads.